# System ID (3 characters) from Windows Server 2016 - for SAP license key generating

Tags: windows-server

I am currently trying to create a SAP license key for our development system which is a Windows Server 2016.

On the form, I am requested to enter a 3 characters long system ID. I tried to find out what this means and where exactly can I find it on the server, but was not successful, mainly because it is required to be 3 characters long.

[image: Picture about the form from SAP Launchpad]

I would like to ask for help to find the 3 characters long system ID on Windows Server 2016.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in Windows itself that would be considered a three character "System ID." Unless this is a value provided by your SAP software, my guess is that this is a value you make up and provide yourself.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. I was not considering this option. I did not installed the SAP yet, bcs I wanted to generate the key first. But in this case I have to change the order.